# SQL getting value of dynamic query into a variable

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am selecting the `COUNT` of something in a SQL Server 2016 database using a dynamic SQL query and want that value placed into a variable. Below is the SQL statement which I was sure was correct, but the value I'm getting is `NULL` (I have tested the query and it returns a value). Any tips?

```
DECLARE @Output INT 

SELECT @SqlCommand = 'SELECT COUNT(ServerName) FROM ' + @TableReference + ' WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ServerName = ''' + @PackageEndPoint + '''' 

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand, N'@Output INT OUTPUT', @Output = @Output OUTPUT

SELECT @StagingRecordCount = @Output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign your @Output variable to your result count.

```
@Output = COUNT(ServerName)
```

**complete script**

```
DECLARE @Output INT 

SELECT @SqlCommand = 'SELECT @Output = COUNT(ServerName) FROM ' + @TableReference + ' WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ServerName = ''' + @PackageEndPoint + ''''

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlCommand, N'@Output INT OUTPUT',@Output = @Output OUTPUT
SELECT  @StagingRecordCount = @Output
SELECT @StagingRecordCount
```